gdb: what are the differences between mi2 and mi3 interface?
The official news page does not say too much and the debugging with gdb book of R. Stallman (link to pdf) only says that m3 was introduced in gdb 9.1. I tried to google more but I couldn't find much more.

The best place to find out what changed is the NEWS file.  This can be read online here.
It turns out there's actually an mi4 !  I guess the manual didn't get updated.
When both mi3 and mi4 were added there's also a corresponding entry in the NEWS files that indicates what was "fixed" in the Mi output.
Here's the entry for when mi3 was added (in GDB 9):
 ** The default version of the MI interpreter is now 3 (-i=mi3).

  ** The output of information about multi-location breakpoints (which is
     syntactically incorrect in MI 2) has changed in MI 3.  This affects
     the following commands and events:

        - -break-insert
        - -break-info
        - =breakpoint-created
        - =breakpoint-modified

     The -fix-multi-location-breakpoint-output command can be used to enable
     this behavior with previous MI versions.

And the entry for mi4 (which was added in GDB 12):
 ** The default version of the MI interpreter is now 4 (-i=mi4).

 ** The "script" field in breakpoint output (which is syntactically
    incorrect in MI 3 and below) has changed in MI 4 to become a list.
    This affects the following commands and events:

        - -break-insert
        - -break-info
        - =breakpoint-created
        - =breakpoint-modified

    The -fix-breakpoint-script-output command can be used to enable
    this behavior with previous MI versions.

